# Fourier series for arbitary functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am unable to understand transition from Fourier series of function with $2\pi$ period to Fourier series of function with arbitrary period, am referring advance engineering mathematics by Erwin here is image of that part in book

[image]

Comment: I think you can just do a variable substitution $t_1 = t_0/k$ and then any function $2\pi k$ periodic will become $2\pi$ periodic.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ has periodic $2p > 0$. Then $f(p x/\pi)$ has period $2\pi$. So
\begin{align}
    f(px/\pi)& \sim \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(py/\pi)dy \\
  &+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(py/\pi)\sin(ny)dx\sin(nx) \\
  &+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(py/\pi)\cos(ny)dy\cos(nx).
\end{align}
Let $w=py/\pi$ so that $dy=(\pi/p) dw$ in the integrals and then let $z=px/\pi$ in $f(px/\pi),\sin(nx),\cos(nx)$ to obtain

\begin{align}
    f(z) &\sim \frac{1}{2p}\int_{-p}^{p}f(w)dw \\
      &+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}\int_{-p}^{p}f(w)\sin(n\pi w/p)dw\sin(n\pi z/p) \\
      &+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}\int_{-p}^{p}f(w)\cos(n\pi w/p)dw \cos(n\pi z/p).
\end{align}